# parsing using php

Tags: php, extract, wikipedia

given a string :

> The [[Pulsatile_flow|pulsatile]]
>   nature of blood flow creates a pulse
>   wave that is propagated down the
>   [[arterial tree]], and at
>   [[Aortic_bifurcation|bifurcations]]
>   reflected waves rebound to return to
>   semilunar valves and the origin of the
>   [[aorta]]. These return waves create
>   the
>   [[Dicrotic_notch#Ventricular_systole|dicrotic
>   notch]] displayed in the aortic
>   pressure curve during the [[cardiac
>   cycle]] as these reflected waves push
>   on the [[heart valve|aortic semilunar
>   valve]].[[Wiktionary:aorta|]]

how could i extract ALL words/phrases enclosed in '[[ ]]' and put then in an array using php.

with condition :
if "|" exist retrieve only words after "|" if no words exist after "|" retrieve the words before "|" but after ":" .
words in parenthesis will also be disregarded.

example

```
[[aorta]]                              => retrieve aortal

[[Pulsatile_flow|pulsatile]]           => retrieve only pulsatile

[[Pulsatile_flow|pulsatile (temp)]]    => retrieve only pulsatile

[[Wiktionary:aorta|Aorta Topic]]       => retrieve Aorta Topic

[[Wiktionary:aorta|]]                  => retrieve aorta

[[aorta|]]                             => retrieve aorta
```

if "|" did not exists retrieve all

> ```
>  [[Wiktionary:aorta]]  => retrieve Wiktionary:aorta
> ```

Comment: Note that if you're trying to parse Wikipedia, it's a lot more difficult due to templates, tables et.c. You might be better off parsing their static HTML dumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
$results = array();
$source = "The [[Pulsatile_flow|pulsatile]] nature of blood flow creates a pulse wave that is propagated down the [[arterial tree]], and at [[Aortic_bifurcation|bifurcations]] reflected waves rebound to return to semilunar valves and the origin of the [[aorta]]. These return waves create the [[Dicrotic_notch#Ventricular_systole|dicrotic notch]] displayed in the aortic pressure curve during the [[cardiac cycle]] as these reflected waves push on the [[heart valve|aortic semilunar valve]].[[Wiktionary:aorta|]]";
if ( preg_match_all('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/is', $source, $matches) ) 
{
    foreach ( $matches[1] as $match ) 
    {
        if ( strpos( $match, '|' ) === false ) {
            $results[] = $match;
        } else {
            $parts = explode( '|', $match );
            if ( empty( $parts[1] ) ) {
                $parts = explode( ':', $parts[0] );
                $results[] = count( $parts ) == 2 ? $parts[1] : $parts[0];
            } else {
                $results[] = preg_replace( '/\(.*?\)/is', '', $parts[1] );
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump( $results );
```

Comment: +1. Regex is a good solution as long as you don't need too many rules surrounding `[[` and `]]` - like escaping, nesting and so on.